# Qt processEvents() and while loop problem

Tags: c++, loops, qt

I am writing an application in Qt (C++) and I have a while loop depending on a certain boolean variable that at the beginning is set to true and when the main widget destructor is called, it is set to false in order to break the loop when the main widget has been closed. However the things don't work as expected.

The following is a sample code that reproduces the situation above.

```
//testwidget.h
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLayout>

class testWidget : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
        testWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
        ~testWidget();
        QPushButton* button;
        QApplication* application;
        QHBoxLayout* layout;
        bool run;
public slots:
        void start();
};
```

.

```
#include "testwidget.h"

testWidget::testWidget(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    run = true;
    application = static_cast<QApplication*>(QApplication::instance());
    button = new QPushButton("BUTTON");
    layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    layout->addWidget(button);
    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(start()));
}

void testWidget::start()
{
    while(run)
    {
        application->processEvents();
    }
}


testWidget::~testWidget()
{
        run  = false;
}
```

.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "testwidget.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[ ])
{
        QApplication app(argc, argv);
        testWidget w;
        w.show();
        return app.exec();
}
```

So when I click the button the loop starts. But if I close the widget (clicking on the "x" close button) the program keeps running (even if the widget disappears).

Whence, if the loop is not started, the program closes normally.

So the destructor is not called if the loop is running.

Probably it depends on the processEvents() method that skips the calling of the destructor, but how can I fix it in a clean way?

At the moment I have "solved" it using `this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);` but it is a sort of forcing.

Comment: The attribute is actually the right way to delete a widget when closing it. Think about it: why would anyone need several ways to do something that works perfectly well in 1 line of code? And putting that aside, the point of your `run` method is to ...?

Comment: In the real application, in the while loop I acquire frames from cameras and process them. I would not want to use this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose); because it gives to me

double free or corruption (out)
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: You could do that in a separate thread and not impact the event loop of the GUI/main thread, couldn't you?

Comment: Yes, I could use threads. But it could be more complicated to handle. I hoped that there will be a more direct way using processEvents().

Answer (score 1):

By using indefinitely blocking function for a slot

```
connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(start()));
```

you basically block the event loop started by `app.exec();` and then you resolve to hacky calls to `application->processEvents();`. It is true that `processEvents` will take care of other signals (widget geometry, clicking on X etc.), but since Slot triggered by `QPushButton::clicked` never returns, neither does `app.exec();`, which leads to the situation where your widget is never destroyed.

Leave the event processing logic to Qt, and if you want to start some async operation, like frame capture, do it in a separate thread, and return from your Slot immediately. E.g.:

```
void testWidget::start()
{
    _worker = std::async(std::launch::async, [this]() { captureLogic(); });
}
```

Note that inside your async function you shouldn't touch any GUI elements. If you want e.g. display a frame, send the Signal to let your widget know it is ready, and display it in the main thread (connected Slot will be fired by the main event loop).